# Why does {comment_url_title_auto_path} not honor URLs across MSM sites?

Tags: multi-site-manager, path, entrylinks

I have a `sidebar/latest-news` template in `siteA` containing a few `{comment_url_title_auto_path}` links, resulting in URLs such as `siteA.com/news/article/[url_title_here]`.

I embed it from a template in `siteB` like this: `{embed="siteA:sidebar/latest-news"}`. When I do so, the URLs that are generated by that template are `siteB.org/news/article/[url_title_here]`.

Is there any way to get it to link to the proper URL over on `siteA`?

> EDIT: Just realized the core of this issue is the fact that the
>   Comment Page URL setting in the channel prefs is
>   `{site_url}/news/article`, and that apparently the `{site_url}` var
>   gets parsed by the parent template's site, not by that channel's site (Edit 2: [reported this as a bug](https://support.ellislab.com/bugs/detail/20993)).
>
> The site in question has multiple country-code subfolders with
>   `index.php` files in them, each one setting custom global vars
>   according to the country. So, going to `siteA.com/us/news/` will set a
>   global var of `{gv_current_country}` to "us" and a
>   `{gv_current_country_category}` var to something like "123" - whatever
>   the ID is of the "USA" category to which entries are assigned.
>
> Therefore, using something like `/news/articles/` in the channel's "Comment Page URL" setting won't work, since it would be tossing the geolocated visitors out of their `siteA.com/[country_code]/` subfolders each time they clicked a link.

Comment: Anyone know if I should change the title to reflect the core of the issue being `{site_url}` used across MSM sites and not `{comment_url_title_auto_path}`?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggeest pasing the site ID you need via am embed parameter al'a `{embed="siteA:sidebar/latest-news" origin={site_id}}` then using the `sites` parameter in the internal comments tag to force the comments to be drawn from the other site.

https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/sites/code.html#specifying-multiple-sites-prepare-for-a-head-trip

That might work as you'd be forcing the comments to be drawn from SiteA. 
Another alternative might be to use the [MSM Site URL](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/msm-site-url) plugin with in the embedded template to get your site_url for siteA,  then build the URL yourself :

```
{exp:msm_site_url site_short_name=sitea"}/news/article/{url_title}
```